# Sharing a location URL for a list

Tags: trello

I know that you can generate a URL for a board or a card but is there any way to generate a URL to share the location of a list?

For example, if I have a board that has 25 lists and I want to send a co-worker the location of that list.

Comment: I just tried it on the welcome board, and hovering over the list gives me the URL "https://trello.com/c/TuXvFIXt/6-or-checklists" which takes me straight to the list. Of course, your URL will be different.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for. If the board has 25 lists, you want to send them a link with all the lists or just a specific list? If the latter is the case, why not simply share the link to the card hosting the list?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to get a link to a list. One can get a link to a specific card but not a list. More info: [Trello help: sharing links to cards and boards](http://help.trello.com/article/824-sharing-links-to-cards-and-boards)